# How to properly subclass jQuery in CoffeeScript?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I want to add some HTML through JavaScript, and add click events on it. Because I don't want to write HTML in JavaScript, I have HTML snippets in my HTML template, inside of `<script type="text/html">` tags, and I want to wrap them in classes (so that it looks nicer and so that I can test the functionality better).

In my example, I have a template with

```
<script type="text/html" id="remove-choice-button">                                
  <span class="close">×</span>
</script>
```

In my CoffeeScript file, I have

```
class RemoveChoiceButton extends jQuery
  constructor: ->
    super($("#remove-choice-button").html().trim())
```

But, if I try to add it to the DOM, it doesn't work, because this happens:

```
jQuery ->

  console.log new RemoveChoiceButton().html()
  //=> undefined
```

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Maybe it's only a typo in your question, but `console.log(new RemoveChoiceButton()).html()` probably does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Fixed. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Btw, isn't it the same as in Ruby, that if you put a space before the parantheses, then they aren't for arguments anymore?

Comment: There is no "proper" way, because this isn't a proper thing to do. jQuery isn't a class, you can't extend it. CoffeeScript isn't magic, its `extend` keyword doesn't turn other random functions into CoffeeScript classes.

Comment: @meagar why do in the jQuery API documentation functions return `jQuery`? Did you mean to say that you can't extend classes that are note created with CoffeeScript's `class` paradigm?

Comment: "Why do in the jQuery API documentation functions return jQuery" What does that have to do with anything? And no, you can't extend arbitrary functions with CoffeeScript's `extend`.

Comment: @meagar, but `jQuery()` is not an arbitrary function, it can be used as a constructor and assigns to `prototype.constructor` accordingly. I'm not familiar enough with CoffeeScript to determine what's wrong here, but I'm pretty sure it *should* work.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It should be.  But I think jQuery internals do some magic and tricky things that don't play well with subclassing.  jQuery seems to be simply not intended to be subclassed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe jQuery works like a typical class.  It's more functional than that.  You don't `instance = new jQuery()` ever.  Javascript allows you to use class based paradigms, but you can't assume everything works that way.

Instead, make the class inherit from nothing and simply *use* jQuery. And provide a method on that class to return a jQuery object.

```
class RemoveChoiceButton extends jQuery
  constructor: ->
    @el = $("#remove-choice-button") # el for DOM *el*ement

  getContent: ->
    @el.html().trim()

console.log new RemoveChoiceButton().getContent()
# or
console.log new RemoveChoiceButton().el.html()
```

---

But it's sounding using a class for this is not what you really want here.  If you want to run a bit of code to get a jQuery object that is a new button, you need no more than a simple function.  Not everything should be a class.

```
makeRemoveChoiceButton = ->
  $($("#remove-choice-button").html().trim())
```

Comment: `jQuery()` is an enhanced constructor but still a constructor, and you definitely can call it with `new` (although you're right it's not seen very much in actual code). Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eS4Dr/).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi what would `new jQuery` do? I'd guess it just ignores its content and acts like it was called without `new`.

Comment: @Jan, yes, IIRC it returns a new object anyway, so changes to `this` inside it are lost when called with `new`. I'll double-check. *Edit:* Double-checked, in 1.10.1 `jQuery()` always returns `new jQuery.fn.init(selector, context, rootjQuery)`, so it indeed works the same whether called in a constructor context or not.

Comment: But is it still possible that I *don't* have to call a method on the instance of `RemoveChoiceButton` to get the jQuery object?

Comment: @janko-m When you use a class, the constructor returns an instance of that class.  If you want something else, don't use a class! `getRemoveChoiceButton = -> $("#remove-choice-button").html().trim()`

Comment: I see. My idea seemed so natural to me that I thought it must be possible. Too bad :/. I will still use a class, but I will implement a `value()` method on it.